# Kubernetes Cluster with Calico - Containers are not coming up & failing with FailedCreatePodSandBox

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I setup kubernetes cluster with Calico as CNI & all nodes are available, However when tried to run container with image nginx then POD remained in creatingContainer Status - I checked for /etc/cni/net.d and /opt/cni/bin on master and worker node, these are are present  on all the nodes (1 master & 1 worker).

```
root@KubernetesMaster:/home/ubuntu# kubeadm version
kubeadm version: &version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"13", GitVersion:"v1.13.4", GitCommit:"c27b913fddd1a6c480c229191a087698aa92f0b1", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-02-28T13:35:32Z", GoVersion:"go1.11.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
root@KubernetesMaster:/home/ubuntu# docker --version
Docker version 18.09.3, build 774a1f4
root@KubernetesMaster:/home/ubuntu#

root@KubernetesMaster:/opt/cni/bin# kubectl get pods
NAME                   READY   STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE
nginx-5c7588df-5zds6   0/1     ContainerCreating   0          21m
root@KubernetesMaster:/opt/cni/bin# kubectl get nodes
NAME               STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION
kubernetesmaster   Ready    master   26m   v1.13.4
kubernetesslave1   Ready    <none>   22m   v1.13.4
root@KubernetesMaster:/opt/cni/bin#

kubectl describe pods
Name:               nginx-5c7588df-5zds6
Namespace:          default
Priority:           0
PriorityClassName:  <none>
Node:               kubernetesslave1/10.0.3.80
Start Time:         Sun, 17 Mar 2019 05:13:30 +0000
Labels:             app=nginx
                    pod-template-hash=5c7588df
Annotations:        <none>
Status:             Pending
IP:
Controlled By:      ReplicaSet/nginx-5c7588df
Containers:
  nginx:
    Container ID:
    Image:          nginx
    Image ID:
    Port:           <none>
    Host Port:      <none>
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       ContainerCreating
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-qtfbs (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             False
  ContainersReady   False
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  default-token-qtfbs:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-qtfbs
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason                  Age                    From                       Message
  ----     ------                  ----                   ----                       -------
  Normal   Scheduled               18m                    default-scheduler          Successfully assigned default/nginx-5c7588df-5zds6 to kubernetesslave1
  Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  18m                    kubelet, kubernetesslave1  Failed create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to set up sandbox container "123d527490944d80f44b1976b82dbae5dc56934aabf59cf89f151736d7ea8adc" network for pod "nginx-5c7588df-5zds6": NetworkPlugin cni failed to set up pod "nginx-5c7588df-5zds6_default" network: stat /var/lib/calico/nodename: no such file or directory: check that the calico/node container is running and has mounted /var/lib/calico/
  Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  18m                    kubelet, kubernetesslave1  Failed create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to set up sandbox container "8cc5e62ebaab7075782c2248e00d795191c45906cc9579464a00c09a2bc88b71" network for pod "nginx-5c7588df-5zds6": NetworkPlugin cni failed to set up pod "nginx-5c7588df-5zds6_default" network: stat /var/lib/calico/nodename: no such file or directory: check that the calico/node container is running and has mounted /var/lib/calico/
  Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  18m                    kubelet, kubernetesslave1  Failed create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to set up sandbox container "30ffdeace558b0935d1ed3c2e59480e2dd98e983b747dacae707d1baa222353f" network for pod "nginx-5c7588df-5zds6": NetworkPlugin cni failed to set up pod "nginx-5c7588df-5zds6_default" network: stat /var/lib/calico/nodename: no such file or directory: check that the calico/node container is running and has mounted /var/lib/calico/
  Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  18m                    kubelet, kubernetesslave1  Failed create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to set up sandbox container "630e85451b6ce2452839c4cfd1ecb9acce4120515702edf29421c123cf231213" network for pod "nginx-5c7588df-5zds6": NetworkPlugin cni failed to set up pod "nginx-5c7588df-5zds6_default" network: stat /var/lib/calico/nodename: no such file or directory: check that the calico/node container is running and has mounted /var/lib/calico/
  Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  18m                    kubelet, kubernetesslave1  Failed create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to set up sandbox container "820b919b7edcfc3081711bb78b79d33e5be3f7dafcbad29fe46b6d7aa22227aa" network for pod "nginx-5c7588df-5zds6": NetworkPlugin cni failed to set up pod "nginx-5c7588df-5zds6_default" network: stat /var/lib/calico/nodename: no such file or directory: check that the calico/node container is running and has mounted /var/lib/calico/
  Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  18m                    kubelet, kubernetesslave1  Failed create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to set up sandbox container "abbfb5d2756f12802072039dec20ba52f546ae755aaa642a9a75c86577be589f" network for pod "nginx-5c7588df-5zds6": NetworkPlugin cni failed to set up pod "nginx-5c7588df-5zds6_default" network: stat /var/lib/calico/nodename: no such file or directory: check that the calico/node container is running and has mounted /var/lib/calico/
  Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  18m                    kubelet, kubernetesslave1  Failed create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to set up sandbox container "dfeb46ffda4d0f8a434f3f3af04328fcc4b6c7cafaa62626e41b705b06d98cc4" network for pod "nginx-5c7588df-5zds6": NetworkPlugin cni failed to set up pod "nginx-5c7588df-5zds6_default" network: stat /var/lib/calico/nodename: no such file or directory: check that the calico/node container is running and has mounted /var/lib/calico/
  Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  18m                    kubelet, kubernetesslave1  Failed create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to set up sandbox container "9ae3f47bb0282a56e607779d3267127ee8b0ae1d7f416f5a184682119203b1c8" network for pod "nginx-5c7588df-5zds6": NetworkPlugin cni failed to set up pod "nginx-5c7588df-5zds6_default" network: stat /var/lib/calico/nodename: no such file or directory: check that the calico/node container is running and has mounted /var/lib/calico/
  Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  18m                    kubelet, kubernetesslave1  Failed create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to set up sandbox container "546d07f1864728b2e2675c066775f94d658e221ada5fb4ed6bf6689ec7b8de23" network for pod "nginx-5c7588df-5zds6": NetworkPlugin cni failed to set up pod "nginx-5c7588df-5zds6_default" network: stat /var/lib/calico/nodename: no such file or directory: check that the calico/node container is running and has mounted /var/lib/calico/
  Normal   SandboxChanged          18m (x12 over 18m)     kubelet, kubernetesslave1  Pod sandbox changed, it will be killed and re-created.
  Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  3m39s (x829 over 18m)  kubelet, kubernetesslave1  (combined from similar events): Failed create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to set up sandbox container "f586be437843537a3082f37ad139c88d0eacfbe99ddf00621efd4dc049a268cc" network for pod "nginx-5c7588df-5zds6": NetworkPlugin cni failed to set up pod "nginx-5c7588df-5zds6_default" network: stat /var/lib/calico/nodename: no such file or directory: check that the calico/node container is running and has mounted /var/lib/calico/
```

On worker node NGINX is trying to come up but getting exited, I am not sure what's going on here - I am newbie to kubernetes & not able to fix this issue -

```
root@kubernetesslave1:/home/ubuntu# docker ps CONTAINER ID IMAGE COMMAND CREATED STATUS PORTS NAMES 5ad5500e8270 fadcc5d2b066 "/usr/local/bin/kube…" 3 minutes ago Up 3 minutes k8s_kube-proxy_kube-proxy-f24gd_kube-system_4e2d313a-4873-11e9-a33a-06516e7d78c4_1 b1c9929ebe9e k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.1 "/pause" 3 minutes ago Up 3 minutes k8s_POD_calico-node-749qx_kube-system_4e2d8c9c-4873-11e9-a33a-06516e7d78c4_1 ceb78340b563 k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.1 "/pause" 3 minutes ago Up 3 minutes k8s_POD_kube-proxy-f24gd_kube-system_4e2d313a-4873-11e9-a33a-06516e7d78c4_1 root@kubernetesslave1:/home/ubuntu# docker ps CONTAINER ID IMAGE COMMAND CREATED STATUS PORTS NAMES 5ad5500e8270 fadcc5d2b066 "/usr/local/bin/kube…" 3 minutes ago Up 3 minutes k8s_kube-proxy_kube-proxy-f24gd_kube-system_4e2d313a-4873-11e9-a33a-06516e7d78c4_1 b1c9929ebe9e k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.1 "/pause" 3 minutes ago Up 3 minutes k8s_POD_calico-node-749qx_kube-system_4e2d8c9c-4873-11e9-a33a-06516e7d78c4_1 ceb78340b563 k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.1 "/pause" 3 minutes ago Up 3 minutes k8s_POD_kube-proxy-f24gd_kube-system_4e2d313a-4873-11e9-a33a-06516e7d78c4_1 root@kubernetesslave1:/home/ubuntu# docker ps CONTAINER ID IMAGE COMMAND CREATED STATUS PORTS NAMES 5ad5500e8270 fadcc5d2b066 "/usr/local/bin/kube…" 3 minutes ago Up 3 minutes k8s_kube-proxy_kube-proxy-f24gd_kube-system_4e2d313a-4873-11e9-a33a-06516e7d78c4_1 b1c9929ebe9e k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.1 "/pause" 3 minutes ago Up 3 minutes k8s_POD_calico-node-749qx_kube-system_4e2d8c9c-4873-11e9-a33a-06516e7d78c4_1 ceb78340b563 k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.1 "/pause" 3 minutes ago Up 3 minutes k8s_POD_kube-proxy-f24gd_kube-system_4e2d313a-4873-11e9-a33a-06516e7d78c4_1

root@kubernetesslave1:/home/ubuntu# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                  COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                  PORTS               NAMES
94b2994401d0        k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.1   "/pause"                 1 second ago        Up Less than a second                       k8s_POD_nginx-5c7588df-5zds6_default_677a722b-4873-11e9-a33a-06516e7d78c4_534
5ad5500e8270        fadcc5d2b066           "/usr/local/bin/kube…"   4 minutes ago       Up 4 minutes                                k8s_kube-proxy_kube-proxy-f24gd_kube-system_4e2d313a-4873-11e9-a33a-06516e7d78c4_1
b1c9929ebe9e        k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.1   "/pause"                 4 minutes ago       Up 4 minutes                                k8s_POD_calico-node-749qx_kube-system_4e2d8c9c-4873-11e9-a33a-06516e7d78c4_1
ceb78340b563        k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.1   "/pause"                 4 minutes ago       Up 4 minutes                                k8s_POD_kube-proxy-f24gd_kube-system_4e2d313a-4873-11e9-a33a-06516e7d78c4_1
root@kubernetesslave1:/home/ubuntu# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                  COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
5ad5500e8270        fadcc5d2b066           "/usr/local/bin/kube…"   4 minutes ago       Up 4 minutes                            k8s_kube-proxy_kube-proxy-f24gd_kube-system_4e2d313a-4873-11e9-a33a-06516e7d78c4_1
b1c9929ebe9e        k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.1   "/pause"                 4 minutes ago       Up 4 minutes                            k8s_POD_calico-node-749qx_kube-system_4e2d8c9c-4873-11e9-a33a-06516e7d78c4_1
ceb78340b563        k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.1   "/pause"                 4 minutes ago       Up 4 minutes                            k8s_POD_kube-proxy-f24gd_kube-system_4e2d313a-4873-11e9-a33a-06516e7d78c4_1
root@kubernetesslave1:/home/ubuntu# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                  COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                  PORTS               NAMES
f72500cae2b7        k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.1   "/pause"                 1 second ago        Up Less than a second                       k8s_POD_nginx-5c7588df-5zds6_default_677a722b-4873-11e9-a33a-06516e7d78c4_585
5ad5500e8270        fadcc5d2b066           "/usr/local/bin/kube…"   4 minutes ago       Up 4 minutes                                k8s_kube-proxy_kube-proxy-f24gd_kube-system_4e2d313a-4873-11e9-a33a-06516e7d78c4_1
b1c9929ebe9e        k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.1   "/pause"                 4 minutes ago       Up 4 minutes                                k8s_POD_calico-node-749qx_kube-system_4e2d8c9c-4873-11e9-a33a-06516e7d78c4_1
ceb78340b563        k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.1   "/pause"                 4 minutes ago       Up 4 minutes                                k8s_POD_kube-proxy-f24gd_kube-system_4e2d313a-4873-11e9-a33a-06516e7d78c4_1
root@kubernetesslave1:/home/ubuntu# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                  COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
5ad5500e8270        fadcc5d2b066           "/usr/local/bin/kube…"   5 minutes ago       Up 5 minutes                            k8s_kube-proxy_kube-proxy-f24gd_kube-system_4e2d313a-4873-11e9-a33a-06516e7d78c4_1
b1c9929ebe9e        k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.1   "/pause"                 5 minutes ago       Up 5 minutes                            k8s_POD_calico-node-749qx_kube-system_4e2d8c9c-4873-11e9-a33a-06516e7d78c4_1
ceb78340b563        k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.1   "/pause"                 5 minutes ago       Up 5 minutes                            k8s_POD_kube-proxy-f24gd_kube-system_4e2d313a-4873-11e9-a33a-06516e7d78c4_1
```

I checked about /etc/cni/net.d & /opt/cni/bin on worker node as well, it is there -

```
root@kubernetesslave1:/home/ubuntu# cd /etc/cni
root@kubernetesslave1:/etc/cni# ls -ltr
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Mar 17 05:19 net.d
root@kubernetesslave1:/etc/cni# cd /opt/cni
root@kubernetesslave1:/opt/cni# ls -ltr
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Mar 17 05:19 bin
root@kubernetesslave1:/opt/cni# cd bin
root@kubernetesslave1:/opt/cni/bin# ls -ltr
total 107440
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  3890407 Aug 17  2017 bridge
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  3475802 Aug 17  2017 ipvlan
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  3520724 Aug 17  2017 macvlan
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  3877986 Aug 17  2017 ptp
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  3475750 Aug 17  2017 vlan
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  9921982 Aug 17  2017 dhcp
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  2605279 Aug 17  2017 sample
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 32351072 Mar 17 05:19 calico
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 31490656 Mar 17 05:19 calico-ipam
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  2856252 Mar 17 05:19 flannel
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  3084347 Mar 17 05:19 loopback
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  3036768 Mar 17 05:19 host-local
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  3550877 Mar 17 05:19 portmap
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  2850029 Mar 17 05:19 tuning
root@kubernetesslave1:/opt/cni/bin#
```

Comment: how did you install calico, is this happening with kubeadm? What pod network CIDR have you specified?

Comment: still need help on this?

Answer (score -1):

You need to run calico node on kubernetes then make sure calico node mount with /var/lib/calico on the host machine

Comment: Thanks for the response but could you please let me know how to mount the same & also on what all containers... Does it require to be mounted on master node or on worker node as well

Comment: Did you install network calico addon 
`https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/create-cluster-kubeadm/#pod-network`

Comment: I use following 2 commands for setting up calico - kubectl apply -f https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.5/getting-started/kubernetes/installation/hosted/etcd.yaml
kubectl apply -f https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.5/getting-started/kubernetes/installation/hosted/calico.yaml

Comment: could show output of : kubectl get pod -n kube-system

Comment: I can see one crash for ```calico-node-749qx                          0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   20         12d```

Comment: root@KubernetesMaster:/home/ubuntu# kubectl get pod -n kube-system
``` NAME                                       READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
calico-etcd-b4r48                          1/1     Running            2          12d
calico-kube-controllers-5cff4f556c-6ckhs   1/1     Running            2          12d
calico-node-749qx                          0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   20         12d
calico-node-hc6hm                          1/1     Running            2          12d ```

Comment: other pod which are running ``` coredns-86c58d9df4-7hxqk                   1/1     Running            2          13d
coredns-86c58d9df4-rnw9m                   1/1     Running            2          13d
etcd-kubernetesmaster                      1/1     Running            2          12d
kube-apiserver-kubernetesmaster            1/1     Running            2          12d
kube-controller-manager-kubernetesmaster   1/1     Running            2          12d
kube-proxy-f24gd                           1/1     Running            3          12d
kube-proxy-ljvz9                           1/1  ```

Comment: You should use kubectl describe pod calico_pod_name to check why it crashed

Comment: using kubectl describe pod <calico_pod_name> does not seem to be found... Response is "Error from server (NotFound): pods "calico-node-749qx" not found" Should I scrap this cluster & try with new one as this has been running from past 12 days

Comment: You need to list calico pod then describe